# Not able to change font size of button text for apple sign-in button

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am unable to change font size for button text for apple sign-in. Is there a way to decrease the size. I tried using text widget but I am unable to assign Text widget to String. I know we can build a button from scratch but is there an efficient way?

Package I am using: https://pub.dev/packages/the_apple_sign_in

I tried changing container width and height but text size remains same

Code for apple sign-in button:

```
if (appleSignInAvailable.isAvailable)
                    Container(
                      height:
                          (1 / 20) * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, //20,
                      width:
                          (1 / 1.6) * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, //20,
                      child: AppleSignInButton(
                        //type: ButtonType.signIn,
                        style: ButtonStyle.black,
                        //buttonText:  '' ,
                        //style: ButtonStyle, // style as needed
                        type: ButtonType.signIn, // style as needed
                        onPressed: () => _signInWithApple(context),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: can you include the package you are using

Comment: Included in the description

Comment: can you also test without `ButtonStyle.black,` or include it. also the parent widget

Comment: So that does not change the font size as ButtonStyle... is for setting colour

Comment: I've tested with dummy data, it is working fine